# .Net Core - How do i access .net core entity framework from another .net core class library (or project)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to access my dbcontext which is in the root of my website project, i have created another .net core class library called ComponentBuilder and in here i have created two classes called IBuild.cs (Interface) and Build.cs (class). So in the startup file i tried adding addscope() but i could not get reference to the ComponentBuilder Library to do this.

So the question is how do i access my dbcontext or entity framework in .net core in another class library?

Inside ComponentBuilder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ComponentBuilder
{
    class Build: IBuild
    {
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ComponentBuilder
{
    class Build: IBuild
    {
    }
}
```

In startup

```
services.AddScoped<IBuild, Build>();
```

Comment: Use dependency injection (DI) where you want to access your class/interface, after you have registered it like you have `services.AddTransient<IBuild, Build>()`? I'd suggest constructor injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, to access *anything*, you must add a reference. That means that for a class library to access a class in your web project, the class library would have to reference the web project. However, you should not actually do that, and you likely *can't* do that because presumably your web project would need to reference this class library you're creating, as well. That would create a circular reference, which cannot happen. Long and short, if your web project needs a class and your class library needs that same class, then you need *another* class library where you can put that class so both projects can reference it there.

Second, you should strong consider whether your class library actually *does* need this in the first place. Class libraries should deal in abstractions. If your class library depends directly on one particular derived context, then it can only work with that. If one the other hand, you depend on `DbContext`, then it can work with anything that utilizes EF Core. That gives your library much greater reusability. Even that could be abstracted though. If your library isn't principally involved in the data layer - it just needs something from the context - then you can depend only on that particular data, and leave it up to the library consumer (i.e. your web app, for example) to do whatever is necessary to get that data. Then, your library is completely agnostic about the data source, and doesn't even require a dependency on EF Core.

The overarching rule of thumb here is that class libraries should be as generic as possible. Only take dependencies when you *absolutely* need them. When possible, leave it up to the library consumer to supply dependencies, and instead reference only primitive types (string, etc.) or abstractions (interfaces/abstract classes).